# $.post('@Url.Action( not working for Safari Browser when deployed on IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am working in MVC 3 Application.
One Of my Jquery Code in Ready is

```
var Isprod = false;
$.post('@Url.Action("TabIndex", "Primary")', {
                value: Isprod
            }, function (data) {
                $("div#divonecomm").html(data);
            });
```

Primary is controller and TabIndex is action
value is bool variable declared in TabIndex method.

This code works fine when run localy for IE,FireFox,Crome and Safari.
When deployed on IIS code runs fine for IE,FireFox,Crome except Safari Browser.

I am not figuring out what is the issue ?

Please suggest what exactly I am missing.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Exactly I'm facing this issue. Is there any help?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the @Url.Action in your rendered html. It may have &amp added to link and remove it

EDIT:

Try this:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("TabIndex", "Primary")', {
            value: "False"
        }, function (data) {
            $("div#divonecomm").html(data);
        });
```

Or this:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("TabIndex", "Primary")', {
            value: "false"
        }, function (data) {
            $("div#divonecomm").html(data);
        });
```

Comment: It give call to TabIndex Properly, but it dont get value for 'value' Parameter when we see erro log, it gives error as The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'value' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult TabIndex(Boolean)' in 'CTS.OneC.OneComm.Reports.Controllers.PrimaryController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.  Parameter name: parameters